# Svg sprites - проблема подключения

Tags: svg, img, спрайт

Всем привет, искал решение на свой вопрос, но все предложенные способы не подошли. Возможно, кто-то решал подобную проблему и сможет мне помочь.
Моя Gulp сборка преобразует svg в спрайт файл подобного типа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставляю в код и обращаюсь по id

```
<svg class="compare-tab__mark">
  <use xlink:href="./img/icons/icons.svg#mark" />
</svg>
```

Работаю в VSCode, запускаю сборку или открываю файл через Go Live, все отображается и работает. Но открываю просто html закинув в браузер и не видит svg. Я уже возился с относительным путем к файлу, но проблема не решилась. Файл лежит в папке на хостинге папка>img>icons>icons.svg
Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто понимает, где или что я не так делаю? Большое спасибо!

Comment: Проблему не решил, но оставил. Суть в том, что через локалу и на проде, svg работают, а если взять папку с проектом и закинуть туда html, то эти же svg не будут работать, не знаю почему, но пока работает на проде, пусть работает) Возможно, кто-то знает причину?